# How to restrict other applications from accessing my images in android phone?

Tags: android, permissions

I don't want to root my phone.
There are some android apps that require permissions - 
1. "modify or delete the contents of your SD card"
2. "read the contents of your SD card"

I want to use the app but I don't want it to read my personal images/data in the phone storage.

Is there any way to hide my images from those apps?
Will putting images to a zip folder work ?
Also, I actually don't have external SD card. All data is in phone's internal storage. So, are these permissions for internal storage also ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden folder you create a hidden folder by adding a `.` before folder name e.g the `name` folder will be like `.name` or create a `.nomedia` file in the folders you want not to be accessed by other application hence media scanner will not scan any folder with `.nomedia` you can do this by using this code:

```
 public static String saveUserImageToSd_2(Bitmap mbmp, String mlocation, String mfilename) {

    final Bitmap bmp = mbmp;
    final String location = mlocation;
    final String filename = mfilename;






     /*--- this method will save your downloaded image to SD card ---*/
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       /*--- you can select your preferred CompressFormat and quality.
    * I'm going to use JPEG and 100% quality ---*/
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
     /*--- create a new folder on SD card ---*/
        File createFolders = new      File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + location);
        createFolders.mkdirs();

        final String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + location + filename;

        fileLocation = fileName;
        System.err.println("fileLocation: 1"+fileName);
        System.err.println("fileLocation: 2"+fileLocation);
        fileExistance(fileName);

        File file = new File(createFolders, filename);
        File noMedia = new File(createFolders, ".nomedia");

        try {
            noMedia.createNewFile();

            file.createNewFile();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     /*--- create a new FileOutputStream and write bytes to file ---*/
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            assert fos != null;
            fos.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




    return fileLocation;

}
```

so this code will create a nomedia file in the directory you specified

or use this code to simply create a hidden folder:
make sure the location looks like `".myFoldername/djkvhsdfherkjghdf/"` where `myFoldername` begins with a `.`

```
 public static String createFolder(String location)
{
    File createFolders = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + location);
    createFolders.mkdirs();
    return createFolders.getAbsolutePath();
}

public static String creatFile(String location, String filename)
{
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + location + filename;
    return filePath;
}

public static File createFolderAndFIle(String location, String filename)
{
    File createFolders = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + location);
    createFolders.mkdirs();

    final String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + location + filename;


    fileExistance(fileName);

    File file = new File(createFolders, filename);
    File noMedia = new File(createFolders, Constant.NOMEDIA);

    try {
        noMedia.createNewFile();
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return file;
  }

  //checking if file exists
  private static void fileExistance(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (file.exists()) {
        deleteFile(filePath);
    }

  }
```